# Why does the twitter bootstrap button in an input-group look wrong in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a rails and bootstrap beginner and trying really hard to get an input group like described here in my program:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups
(Please scroll down to "Button addons")

I'm trying to get this right in may rails program, but it looks completely different (and wrong):

[image: Button not aligned, wrong colour]

That's my code in the view:

```
<%- model_class = Score -%>
<%= form_tag scores_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= button_tag t(:search), :name => nil, class: ["btn","btn-    default"] %>
      </span>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control",     placeholder: "Search for..." %>
    </div> <!-- input-group -->
  </div> <!-- col-lg-6 -->
</div> <!-- row -->
<% end %>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%= t( :list_model, model: Score.model_name.human( :count => 2) )%> (<%= Score.count%>) </h1>
</div>
```

And thats the generated html:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/scores" method="get"><div     style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden"     value="&#x2713;" /></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Suchen</button>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" id="search" name="search"     placeholder="Search for..." type="text" />
    </div> <!-- input-group -->
  </div> <!-- col-lg-6 -->
</div> <!-- row -->
</form>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Liste der Stücke (103) </h1>
</div>
```

I'm using the twitter-bootsrap gem:

```
% bundle show twitter-bootstrap
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8
```

Hmm, 2.2.8? Is this the gem-version or the bootstrap version? In each case, it's wrong somehow: the homepage mentions version 3.2 of the gem ?!?

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

When trying the examples e.g. in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp, everything looks fine, so it has to be my program, but I have no idea where to look :(

Update: That's what is included in the header:

```
% wget -q -O- "http://localhost:3000/scores" | grep -i bootstrap
<link data-turbolinks-track="true"     href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all"     rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true"     src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1">    </script>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `bootstrap.js` included on your page?

Comment: Your html looks good, and the buttons should be joined. yeah, check what nate suggested and make sure the css files are there.

Comment: bootstrap.js is included, see my update.